# Javascript Binding Templates to Data

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I really like handlebars.js templates, but I want to hook up data binding to update the template when the data changes. I already know how to do something like this:

```
var users = ['hello','world','third'];
var source = '<form>{{#each users}}<input type="text" value="{{this}}">{{/each}}</form>';
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$('.form-cont').html(template({users: users}));
```

If I want to add another user later

```
users.push('last');
```

Now to update the template I update the HTML

```
$('.form-cont').html(template({users: users}));
```

I would like only things that have changed to be updated, in the above code the original html is wiped out and replaced with the new template. Is there a way to only update what is changed? Meaning add an item in the each without wiping out the original inputs.

I know that Knockout.js, Angular.js and Ember.js have this built into their frameworks. I am looking for a more lightweight solution that only handles template binding, not an entire framework. Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars doesn't have data binding built-in. Ember.js and Sproutcore use Handlebars templates with data binding extensions. There are also libraries like juggy/backrub or backbone.modelbinding for integrating with Backbone.js. Also take a look at mikeric/rivets for general data binding support. A lightweight option might be to use an evented array implementation with pub-sub capabilities, e.g. azer/new-list.